# Sending form data to PayPal checkout

Tags: php, forms, paypal, checkout

Ok here is problem, I am sending form data via radio buttons to a PayPal checkout but it works when you first upload the php file and takes the correct values, but if you return and select say the next radio button and submit it then changes the submit info to the value you sent before almost overiding it?

```
<table class="procut_item" border="0" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<td width="auto"><h4>Product test</h4></td>
<td width="auto"><form method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemQty" value="1" />
 Size:<input type="radio" name="itemname" value="1">10 x 10</select>   
<input class="dw_button" type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Buy" />    
</td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td width="auto"><h4>Product test</h4></td>
<td width="auto"><form method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="itemprice" value="30" />
<input type="hidden" name="itemQty" value="1" />
 Size:<input type="radio" name="itemname" value="1">10 x 10</select>   
<input class="dw_button" type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Buy" />      
</td>
<tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

With seeing all of the code and how it is being handled, my first guess would be that you are usnig the same variable name, and it is overriding the first.  You could could create an array if not already using one, or increment the variable name by appending a number to it.

Comment: I am unable to change the variable name as this is set to pay-pals checkout if i close of each part of the input fields it also then stops me from selecting multiple choice.